# json encoding isn't considering encoding argument in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, encoding

Trying to encode a json file using the utf catalog (utf-8-sig), with this code

```
data =json.load(open("data.json", encoding = "utf-8-sig"))
```

But it appears that the encoding argument is being ignored throwing this error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app1.py", line 11, in <module>
    print(k,v)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xb0' in position 141: ordinal not in
range(128)
```

Edit: the datatype of the file data.json is `<class '_io.TextIOWrapper'>`, and here's the full stack:

```
import json
data =json.load(open("data.json", encoding = "utf-8-sig"))
for k,v in data.items():
    print(k,v)
```

Edit2:Binary sample of the file using `print(open("data.json"), "rb").read(180)`

> b'{"abandoned industrial site": ["Site that cannot be used for any
>   purpose, being contaminated b y pollutants."], "abandoned vehicle":
>   ["A vehicle that has been discarded in the envir'

Comment: Are you sure that's the failing line? Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: @tdelaney, just posted now the full stack and the data type for when I open "data.json"

Comment: Try testing just the read: `tmp = open("data.json", encoding = "utf-8-sig").read(256)`. Also it would be interesting to post a binary sample of the file (perhaps `print(open("data.json"), "rb").read(180)`)

Comment: The stack trace didn't seem to make it into the edit.

Comment: If the problem was loading the data, it would be a `decode` error. What is `sys.stdout.encoding` ? Just trying to figure out where the encoding (as opposed to decoding) is happening and why its ascii.

Comment: @tdelaney I edited to show the full error. Just the read works fine. Also just edited the post to show the binary sample of the file. And sys.stdout.encoding is US-ASCII

Comment: That's your problem. You can't print non-ascii data on an ascii terminal. You could do the decode yourself and substitute ? for unknown charse.

Comment: `print(k.encode('ascii', 'replace'), v.encode('ascii', 'replace'))`

Answer (score 0):

As @tdelaney pointed out in comments, you are looking the wrong problem:

The error in not on `open`, nor in `json.read`, not in the `data.items()` iteractor, so it is not a **decoding** problem, between `utf-8-sig` and unicode string.

But the problem is in `print`. The problem is **encoding**, so it means that the error is between unicode string in python and a resulting *binary* encoding. In this case, the unicode string is converted into `ascii`, but ascii cannot represent all original characters.

There are two solutions:

- you can allow your terminal to accept UTF-8 characters. This could by done by setting e.g. `LANG=C.UTF-8` (supported only on few systems) or `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` or other locales (check on your system what locales support UTF-8).
- you force print to print only ascii, as proposed by @tdelaney `print(k.encode('ascii', 'replace'), v.encode('ascii', 'replace'))`. You may want to change `replace` with `backslashreplace` or `ignore`. (see https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#codec-base-classes).

There are also hybrid solution (but not really safe and portable on all systems) (like forcing python to output in a particular encoding), and many hacks, but it will make your code complex, so I do not recommend it (and you should wrap them in a new function).